# Regex in R: get last n sentences before a keyword

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to get a number of sentences (3 in this case) before a particular keyword ('Keyword' in this case). If the text says:

`Hi Stack Overflow. This is a random text. This is another text. Hello. Keyword Test test`

It should get me the last 3 sentences before the word "Keyword", i.e.

`This is a random text. This is another text. Hello.`

This is the regex I have so far but it just returns me `Hello.`:

`.*([A-Z].*\.\s){3}(?=Keyword).*`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/JKfFLl/7

Comment: What is the code you use the regex with?

Comment: `sub("^.*\\. (([^.]+\\.){3}) ?Keyword.*", "\\1", your_string)` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?m)^.*?\b((?:[^.]*\.){1,3})(?=\s*[\w\s]+Keyword\b).*?$
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/h1nRNb/8)**

**r**

```
x <- c(
     'Hi Stack Overflow. This is a random text. This is another text. Hello. Keyword Test test',
     'This is a sentence. And another sentence. List of Keyword 1. some text 2. some text. Another sentence.'
    )
    gsub('(?m)^.*?\\b((?:[^.]*\\.){1,3})(?=\\s*[\\w\\s]+Keyword\\b).*?$','\\1', x, perl=T)
```

Comment: What if the text is `Hi Stack Overflow. This is a random text. This is another text. Hello. Test Keyword Test test`?

Comment: I tried adding `.*` between the capturing group and positive lookahead, but it returns me `Hi Stack Overflow. This is a random text. This is another text.` instead of `This is a random text. This is another text. Hello.`

Comment: @vdvaxel just change the word `Keyword` to that word. see [here](https://regex101.com/r/h1nRNb/4)

Comment: Yes, but what if you don't know what that word is?

Comment: The keyword will always appear, but it is possible that there's another word or several other words before it. In an ideal situation, I want it to ignore these words and only take the full sentences before it. For example it might say `This is a sentence. And another sentence. List of Keyword 1. some text 2. some text. Another sentence.` and the ideal output would be `This is a sentence. And another sentence.`

Comment: @vdvaxel That's not an issue. But you must need to know the keyword to get the ideal output.

Comment: I know the keyword (assume it's just 'Keyword' for now), but the question is how do I change the code? :) I tried putting `.*` between the capturing group and positive lookahead but that doesn't work.

Comment: @vdvaxel check updated answer. now it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that quantifier for capturing groups only return the last group.

Try this

`((?:[^.]+\.){3})(?=\s?Keyword).*`

see: https://regex101.com/r/JKfFLl/8

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `sub`:

```
text <- "Hi Stack Overflow. This is a random text. This is another text. Hello. Keyword Test test"

regex <- ".*?\\s*((?:[^.]+\\.){3})\\s*Keyword.*"

sub(regex, "\\1", text, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "This is a random text. This is another text. Hello."
```

Comment: Since you specify `perl = TRUE`, the `.` does not match line breaks. It would be safer to add `(?s)` at the start of the regex pattern (so that eventual line breaks could be matched with `sub`, too)